# Is it possible to get the website url from a destination IP?

Tags: networking, dns

I've been setting up data visualizations for my Fortigate device, and logs from the device just give the destination IP of the app the user is accessing. I want to know if it is possible to know the website url of each destination ip supplied by the raw logs of the device. Thank you

Comment: No. A URL contains a port and a path as well as a hostname, and you can't recover the first two at all from an IP address, and you can't necessarily get the correct hostname from the IP address if it is a multi-hosting server.

Comment: But maybe you can modify your device settings so it adds the required information to logs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the hostnames for the given IP address using the reverse IP lookup tools. 
Looking up for URLS is something not supported off the shelf, however you can do further some lookups once you know the hostname.